# What perks apply to the Syringer Rifle in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been thinking of creating a stealth/ [Syringer Rifle](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Syringer) character build for Fallout 4. The general idea is a character who relies on short range stealth melee and long range Syringer Rifle attacks to get by.

The Syringer Rifle is different from every other Fallout 4 weapon (I know of) in that you have to craft your own ammo - and most of the [Syringer Ammo](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Syringer_ammo) is non-lethal.

This makes me wonder about what [Fallout 4 Perks](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_perks) apply to the Syringer Rifle. For example does [Riflesman](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rifleman) or [Ninja](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ninja) increase the damage for Bleed-out or Radscorpion venom syringes?

And does Luck have any effect on the syringes with "Chance" effect? If I select a Critical in VATS will the "Chance" effect always be applied?

What perks apply to the Syringer Rifle in Fallout 4?

Comment: In all the time I've played this game, I've never bothered using the Syringer Rifle. I better investigate.

Comment: @DCShannon - me neither. But I thought it might make an interesting build. I'm enjoying builds with artificial constraints at the moment to keep the challenge up.

Comment: Making a melee character on survival was pretty challenging. Up until around level 30. Not too long after that I was more deadly than my shooter builds. 12x sneak attack is devastating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Syringer page on Nukapedia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Syringer#Perks),

> The Syringer does not benefit from Quick Hands, Rifleman, Mister Sandman, Bloody Mess, or Ninja, but Sniper 1 and 3 both work.

It's not automatic or a pistol, so Gunslinger and Commando wouldn't work either.

Sniper 1 is

> It's all about focus. You have improved control and can hold your breath longer when aiming with scopes.

and Sniper 3 is

> Non-automatic, scoped rifles gain +25% accuracy to head shot in V.A.T.S.

I can't find any information on critical hits with the Syringer at all. Not sure if it has any effect. Needs testing.

If luck improves your % chance for the rifle's random effects, I see no evidence to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Syringer), there are confirmed perks that do *not* work with the Syringer...

> The Syringer does not benefit from Quick Hands, Rifleman, Mister Sandman, Bloody Mess, or Ninja, but Sniper 1 and 3 both work.

Comment: Jinx (plus more characters)

Comment: @DCShannon well this is awkward

Comment: I did say I was going to investigate.

Comment: I at least hyperlinked all the perks in my answer :p

Answer (score 2):

According to [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Syringer):

> The Syringer does not benefit from [Quick Hands](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Quick_Hands), [Rifleman](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rifleman), [Mister Sandman](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mister_Sandman), [Bloody Mess](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bloody_Mess_(perk)), or [Ninja](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Ninja), but [Sniper](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sniper) 1 and 3 both work.